# Beta coefficient significantly larger than semipartial correlation, but no collinearity?

Tags: r, correlation, multiple-regression, effect-size

I've fit a multiple regression model with two predictors, one continuous  and one categorical (male/female, dummy coded). For the first (continuous) variable, the standardized coefficient and semipartial correlation are nearly identical in size ($\beta_1 = -.43$, $s r_1 = -.43$). For the second variable, however, there is a large difference in these two effect sizes ($\beta_2 = .46$, $s r_2 = .20$).

My understanding was that a large difference between the beta and semi-partial correlation was indicative of collinearity between the predictors, so I went and checked this - but to my surprise, the point biserial correlation between the two variables was negligible ($r_{12} = 0.007$), as was the VIF in the model ($1.0004$).

I'm not a statistician by training and am at a bit of a loss as to why this might be the case. Does anyone have any ideas, or resources I might look at to understand this finding better? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the .20 is not the *squared* semipartial correlation?

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I double checked, because boy wouldn't that have been embarrassing, but no, it is not the squared semipartial, hence also the values for the first predictor being in line with expectations. I'm using [jtools' summ](https://rdrr.io/cran/jtools/src/R/summ.R) function, if that helps.

Comment: I have another guess or 2 that would require seeing the min, max, mean, and sd for each variable as well as all the zero-order r values.  Or having access to your data - just the 3 variables in question.  Cheers ~

Comment: while preparing reproducible data/code for you, I've honed in on the problem - what I thought was the beta for the categorical predictor was actually the unstandardized estimate; R's treatment of factors was effectively dummy coding for me _after_ the scaling of the continuous variables. when I also scale the categorical variable (which, to be honest, is intuitively strange to me for a binary variable), the two effect sizes make sense in relation to each other again. Not as embarrassing as mistaking a squared semipartial correlation, but embarrassing nonetheless!

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help in any case, positive first experience on SE for me :)

Comment: You're welcome; glad to hear it :-)